# YAxis not show when Position set OUTSIDE_CHART and XAxis also not show OUTSIDE

Tags: java, android

when i set

```
YAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE);
```

it work fine, but not work for OUT_SIDE position

Answer (score 5):

i just find the mistake, i have used

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

that why outer axis not showing